# running or building docker results in net.ipv4.ip_forward being reset

Tags: ip, forwarding, sysctl

this is on a rhel6 system (docker 1.7.1 from epel).

basically, everytime i do a build or a run, i can see that the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` sysctl gets reset to `0` - which results in the container loosing all network connectivity.

i think this is related to a new interface being added (eg veth7458c81).

question is how can i prevent `net.ipv4.ip_forward` being reset?

Comment: Is it in /etc/sysctl.conf?

Comment: good point... i added it to `sysctl.conf`... and same! :(